# Portlets size handling

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6.1.1.

I have created a portlet in eclipse through pluggin sdk 6.1.1.

Now i wants change the size of the portlet.

How can i change it?

Help me

Comment: _change the size of the portlet_, what does this mean? Can you explain a little better.

Comment: In my portlet,only single line content is there.when i placed the portlet in a page,it takes a default size.how can i set the size of portlet same as size of content(Single line).

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, through the Page's Layout (log as admin, Manage, Page Layout). It's a good practice to have your portlet visuals/styling generic, so that it can adapt to the hosting page's theme and layout, to keep it usable for later projects and different portal configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's done through theme's css and layout templates. But you may use some css right in your portlet.  Also a portlet might have been maximized and minimized so don't take too much css in your portlet.

Comment: yes.. i tried some css.but no use.can you give me some eg css code..?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own css for portlet instance:

> Options->Look and Feel->Advenced Styling

Add a CSS rule for just this portlet.

Example:

```
#portlet_56_INSTANCE_ENG7BaroFy5f{
    width: 800px;
    height: 440px;
}
```